# App unresponsive when gettings values from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-8.0

I am trying to understand how I can store and archive values from my `appsettings.json`. The program is a simple .NET 8 console app.

I am using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` & `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` to achieve this.

Here is my code:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mySettingValue = GetValues();

        Console.WriteLine($"Hello {mySettingValue[1]}");
    }

    static string GetValues()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        var mySettingValue = configuration["MySetting"];

        return mySettingValue;
    }
}
```

When debugging, my app is running fine until I get to:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();
```

Here the code is unresponsive, but not in debug either. I am to believe it is waiting for something, but I am not sure what causes this problem.

Please, if anyone have anything that might help me understand what I am doing wrong, please do let me know.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Unresponsive how? Or is it abending? Does `appsettings.json` exist in the same directory as the executable? If you change `optional` to `true`, does it return and proceed to the next statement? `appsettings.json` is set to "Copy if newer" by ASP.NET Core projects, but if you started with the Console Applicatoin template, that won't be the case and you have to change that property yourself. There's not enough information in your question to help you but answers to these questions might give us enough.

Comment: Hello @madreflection.

Thank you for the time to read and respond to the post.

The app is running, but does not go any further in the code. It simple stands and wait. When I "Step into" in debug, it just waits there, and I can't go any further in debug mode. 

I have tried to remove the optional, but nothing happens, same if I turn it to true.

The appsettings.json is 'copy never', but I am not sure what this propperty does, I'll look into this :) 

Sorry if there is missing any details, but I am unsure myself what I need to give, as there is simply not much to give out from. :)

Comment: It must be "Copy if newer" (or Copy always) so it gets copied to the output folder. "Copy never" means it's definitely NOT in the output folder, the same folder as the executable and the "current directory" as returned by `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, so it isn't being found. It should be throwing an exception; the first-change exception handling might be causing it to hang, but it's just a guess.

Comment: Note: Are you expecting `mySettingValue` to be an array?  It's just a string, so you are saying "Hello X" to the second letter in your string.

Comment: What is returned by `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`? I am curious if it is a local path or a virtual drive or network share. If it's a nonlocal resource I could imagine your program seeming to hang while it attempts to access it.

Comment: Perhaps try: 

`.SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)`